# How many bits in the binary representation of positive integer n?

Tags: computer-science

I wrote Log base 2 of N on my exam, and got the question wrong. How could this possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is detail explanation for your question.](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/)

Comment: Please avoid answering with links to external content.